# Adding multiple sorting/filtering options to list - best approach?

Tags: vue.js, sorting, vuejs2

I've got a list of books that I've added a search filter to using computed properties, however, I'd also like to add some other options to sort the list with and I'm feeling lost in how to approach it.

So my list is like so:

```
 <BookCard
        v-for='book in (
            filteredBooks
          )'
        :key='book.id' :book='book'
/>
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can just apply multiple filters to that component? I might be thinking about it completely wrong.

My goal is to also have a button that can toggle sorting alphabetically when clicked (asc/dsc) and perhaps another option to sort by publish date (asc/dsc).

Could I just add another computed property like:

```
  computed: {
    filteredBooks() {
      return this.books.filter((book) => book.volumeInfo.title
        .toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()));
    },

    sortedByDate() {
      ...
    },
  },
```

and then add that like:

```
<BookCard
        v-for='book in (
            filteredBooks,
            sortedByDate
          )'
        :key='book.id' :book='book'
/>
```

Not exactly sure how to go about it.

I'd be really grateful for an example of how I should approach this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you might want to approach this is to define search parameters object or array and use a single `computed` parameter for the sorted result

For example

```js
computed: {
  booksResult(){
    return this.books
      .filter(book => {
         // apply filter options
      })
      .sort((a,b) => {
         // apply sort options using this.sortParams
         const {desc, key} = this.sortParams
         return desc ? a[key] >= b[key] : a[key] <= b[key];
      })
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a sort function in action (vanilla, without Vue)

```js
const fruits = [
  {"name" : "Apple", "weight": 1.2, "price" : 35},
  {"name" : "Banana", "weight": 0.9, "price" : 12},
  {"name" : "Grapes", "weight": 0.1, "price" : 45},
  {"name" : "Pineapple", "weight": 1.4, "price" : 200}
]

const sortFunction = ({key, desc=true}) => fruits.sort((a,b) => {
    return desc ? a[key] >= b[key] : a[key] <= b[key]
})

console.log(sortFunction({key:'name', desc:false}).map(f => f.name).join(', '))

console.log(sortFunction({key:'weight'}).map(f => `${f.name} ${f.weight}t`).join(', '))
```

I see in your example that you have nested objects (`book.volumeInfo.title`) which make lookup using a string key a bit more complicated, so you may need to include some logic to convert `book[key]` when `volumeInfo.title` is the key into something like `book[key0][key1]`.

You can even have multiple parameters to sort by, just increases the complexity a bit, but you can still solve it using a single computed

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to give me or point me to an example of this approach?

Comment: updated. Also (though not vue) here's an implementation that does something similar in svelte. In this case, I'm using a map to generate the key to sort on https://github.com/dasDaniel/svelte-table/blob/develop/src/SvelteTable.svelte#L33